# Stretch right sidebar background to the right edge of the screen

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make my right sidebar's background blue color extend to the right edge of the screen. Right now the sidebar is in a fixed layout. The arrows in the image show where I would like the background to be blue.

[image]

EDIT: Added some code as requested.

Comment: We'll need to see some code to be able to help you. Can you post your html and css, or a codepen to demonstrate your problem?

Comment: Put that sidebar in parent container, position it on left. Give needed width to the parent and  make it's background blue as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `container` to remain 400px wide (which I assume you want), you can assign a linear gradient background with an abrupt color change at 50% to the `body` as shown below. (Also add `margin: 0`to the body to prevent default margins.)

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #fff 0%, #fff 50%, #00f 50%, #00f 100%);
  margin:0;
}
.container {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.main-content {
  width: 75%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 25%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-content"></div>
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh nice, that is an interesting solution. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. The grey area is where you can put your sidebar.

**Updated**: Full width containers with a fixed sidebar.

```css
.container-fluid {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 330px + 15px * 2);
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.fixed-container {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}

.main-content {
  width: inherit;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar {
  width: inherit;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
}

.sidebar .bar {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="main-content column">
      <div class="foo"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fixed-container">
  <div class="sidebar column">
    <div class="bar"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Hewlett, but when I make my screen size larger than the container divs width the blue right sidebar should still be at the right edge of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

## Procedure

To achieve the desired effect based on your **HTML** layout, set the sidebar width to `100%` viewport width subtracted by the parent container width `400px`, divided by `2`, then plus the `25%` width of the container (i.e. `25% + (100vw - 400px) / 2`).

Then set the margin right, negative value of the `100%` viewport width subtracted by the parent container width `400px`, divided by `2` (i.e. `25% + (100vw - 400px) / 2 * -1`).

## CSS

```
.sidebar {
  width: calc(25% + calc(100vw - 400px /* 400px is the width of the .container */) / 2);
  margin-right: calc(calc(100vw - 400px /* 400px is the width of the .container */) / 2 * -1);
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  float:left;
}
```

**Heads up** change the value `400px` according to the set `.container` width.

## Test

Fill the sidebar with lots of contents to see it in action.